# Mispositioning in CSS

Tags: html, css, position

I'm quite new into HTML&CSS and I'm having troubles with the model box I think.

Here both elements below "Personal data" aren't at the same height and I can't find the reason. Can anyone help me?

jsfiddle.net/jbzgmqns/

PS: Don't worry about being ugly, everything included the borders are just placeholders.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Relevant code needs to be directly included in the question, not only on 3rd-party sites.

Comment: The elements _are_ the same height, as specified - but `p` elements have default margins from the browser stylesheet. Set those to 0.

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because **`<P>...</p>`** itself is taking margin.
Set its margin value '0' i.e. `margin:0;` to keep it in same level of image.

And take `<p>` inside `<div class="cuadro">...</div>` as shown below

```
<div class="cuadro">
                <h1>Personal Data</h1>
                <div class="imagen">
                    <img src="http://gobierno.morelos.gob.mx/sites/default/files/images/transparencia/placeholder-transparencia.jpg" />
                </div>
                <p style="margin: 0;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                    <br> Donec efficitur eros quis sapien congue, hendrerit rhoncus magna cursus.
                    <br> Nam a blandit diam. Curabitur auctor, ipsum eget mattis vulputate, elit ex egestas nunc, sit amet molestie
                    <br> ante felis porta ligula. Aenean elementum justo sed placerat finibus.</p>
            </div></div>
```

Comment: The margin:0; actually fixed it, really appreciated! But then what I understand from that is the margin isn't 0 by default?

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation Alex,
In reply I must say YES, actually when you write <body></body>, it takes few margin from left and top side.
In order to resolve that one need to set margin 0 for body to keep full screen designed without that unnecessary space.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your code you defined the block height, when you shouldn't:

```
.block {
  height: 700px;
```

Just remove that and all will be fine.

Comment: then also remove the 'height: 400px;' you set for your '.cuadro img'